# subscribe event with image object - WPF

Tags: wpf, image, events, element, subscribe

So I am trying to subscribe the event `MouseLeftButtonUp` on an image element (lets name it "TheImage") in a WPF project. I want to be able to call the event handler when I click in the image element. How can I do that?

Comment: for starters, use commands ([MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)) not Code-behind event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) is a `UIElement`, so you can directly subscribe to [`MouseLeftButtonUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup.aspx).

Comment: Just in case others need it, I found a useful link from msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using MVVM approach, you'll need Galasoft MvvmLight (install via Nuget).

At head of your XAML:

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

OBS.: if you're not using WPF45, replace "WPF45" for version that you're using, on

In your image:

```
<Image>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding YourCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Image>
```